# Grep the specific values with jq

Tags: jq

```
{
  "Value": "test-CDB-CCP-CONSUL_ACL",
  "Key": "Name"
}
{
  "Value": "yes",
  "Key": "Schedule"
}
{
  "Value": "ENGINEERING-PLATFORM",
  "Key": "Department"
}
{
  "Value": "clustr.dev@tallysolutions.com",
  "Key": "Owner"
}
{
  "Value": "kalyan.g@tallysolutions.com",
  "Key": "Owner"
}
{
  "Value": "No",
  "Key": "Schedule"
}
```

Hi guys,
I have above code, i want to display the below values as follows

Schedule, Yes

Schedule, No

I tried below commands but didn't works for me

aws ec2 describe-instances| jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[].Values'

aws ec2 describe-instances| jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input shown above, you'd use this command:

```
jq --slurp --raw-output 'map(select(.Key == "Schedule") | "\(.Key), \(.Value)") | .[]'
```

But I don't think that what you've posted is the actual input you have; it's likely the output of one of the two commands shown. If that's the case, then take the `map()` and probably the `.[]` from my command and append onto the end of what you have already.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS CLI has an in-built equivalent to the `jq` command by using the `--query` parameter.

You can use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[?Key==`Schedule`].[Key,Value]' --output text
```

(This format worked on my Mac using zsh. For other operating systems, you might need to play with the quote characters.)

It is basically saying:

- For each instance
- For each Tag with a Key of 'Schedule'
- Retrieve the Tag's Key and Value

For reference, see: [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)